# Filtering array list

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, filter

I have a class which I want to use, to filter my array according to driver. Driver is hardcoded just to try and eliminate possibilities of why the code is not working. I have tried a lot of different methods none seem to working. I get the error `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0` after my line of `println(driverList[3].DELNO)`.

```
   private fun datafilter(tripsheetlist: ArrayList<DataModel>, driver: String): List<DataModel> {
   println("driver in datafilter subclass")
   println(driver)
   
   println("tripsheetlist[3].DELNO")
   println(tripsheetlist[3].DELNO)
   
   var driverList: List<DataModel> = tripsheetlist

   //   var driverList : ArrayList<DataModel> = tripsheetlist.filter { s -> s == driver }
   var i = 0
   while (  i != tripsheetlist.size){
        driverList = tripsheetlist.takeWhile { tripsheetlist[i].DRIVER == "JIM" }
       i++
   }
 
   println("driverList[3].DELNO")
   println(driverList[3].DELNO)

       return driverList
   }
```

Below is DataModel

```
class DataModel(
   var TRIPSHEETNO: Int,
   var WONUMBER: String,
   var DELNO: Int,
   var CUSTOMER: String,
   var DRIVER: String,
   var WEIGHT: Double,
   var state: DataState = DataState.Unselected
   )
```

After the filter I have seen it returns as an `List` and not `ArrayList`. I have established that this does not affect my data.

Thank you for all suggestions.

Solution :

```
private fun datafilter(tripsheetlist: ArrayList<DataModel>, driver: String): ArrayList<DataModel> {
   return ArrayList(tripsheetlist.filter { it.DRIVER == driver }) }
```

Comment: you should probably avoid specifying ``ArrayList`` unless you have a good reason - in Kotlin you generally just use the ``List`` and ``MutableList`` types, so you don't worry about the exact implementation, and you don't need to go converting things to ``ArrayList`` or ``HashMap`` or whatever just to make them work with your other functions (this goes for Java too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1 Size: 0` might be coming from `println(driverList[3].DELNO)` line, after you use `takeWhile` on the `list` as you are trying to access the `index` that is not available in the `list`.

Here

```
tripsheetlist.takeWhile { tripsheetlist[i].DRIVER == "JIM" }
```

in `takeWhile` you've are comparing the `DRIVER` of only first item, so it would either return `emptyList` when the first item's `DRIVER` won't be `JIM` or the full list when the first item's `DRIVER` value would be `JIM`.

You should not use `takeWhile` for your use case, as it would only return the items at the beginning of the list which match your given condition. So, if your first item's `DRIVER` is not `JIM` it would return an `emptyList` and if your first two item's `DRIVER` is `JIM`, it would return those two only and won't check for remaining items.

You should use `filter` and your method can be refactored like this

```
private fun datafilter(tripsheetlist: ArrayList<DataModel>, driver: String): List<DataModel> {
    return tripsheetlist.filter { it.DRIVER == driver }
}
```

> After the filter I have seen it returns as an List and not ArrayList

`filter` and `takeWhile` return a `list`, so if you want an `ArrayList`. You have to cast it as `ArrayList` like this

```
ArrayList(tripsheetlist)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have tried filter without it working previously. Seems my wording/code must have been wrong. Thank you for solving my problem and changing my 20 lines of code in to 2. ツ